# Is it breast or breasts when talking about one person

Tags: word-usage

When you talk about a person's breast do you say “breast” or “breasts”.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on whether you are talking about someone's breast meaning their whole chest area as the phrase "[beat their breast](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beat+his+breast)" or breast as in [mammary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammary_gland) in which case you'd use breast to describe one and breasts for the plural.

Answer (score 0):

Singular if you refer to the front of the abdomen; plural if you refer to both of a woman's (to put it crudely) boobs.

Respectively definitions 1 and 3 of http://www.dictionary.com/browse/breast?s=t

Comment: The front of the abdomen is the belly (or abdomen). The sternum and front of the ribs is the chest or breast.

Comment: [Thorax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorax) would be the medical term.